# If I develop in React Native is it safe to update to macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, react-native, macos-mojave

I've seen that there have been some issues related to developing / building React Native apps with macOS Mojave. Wondering if these have been resolved, and if it would be safe for me to update at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can update to Mojave. I've been on Mojave from the first beta version, and never really get any problem. So yes as today you can update to Mojave with no problem. Just make sure to install new update components in Xcode. This will install when you will open Xcode for the first time after the update.